# Getting error while using firebase crashlytics with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I'm using this library https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics to use crashlytics in my app and then i have added every configuration needed to configure crashlytics in flutter project and crashlytics also gets initialized but then i get error called settings request failed.

project level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

//Added this dependency
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
```

Then in app level build.gradle

```
//Applied this plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'

//Added this dependency
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
}
```

I have also added google-services.json file downloaded from firebase console in the android/app folder.

But when i run the application i get this error

[image]

Comment: Just to rule out the possibility, have you run pub get or gradle sync after making the gradle changes

Comment: Yes i have, otherwise i wouldn't have been able to import library in my classes. @NemiShah

Comment: Is this app a migrated app from Fabric?

Comment: No, I have added all the dependencies according to latest google document. @KevinKokomani

Comment: There's a new version of the plugin you're using, could you try that out and see if it helps?

Comment: I'm using the latest version given in the above link so if you're suggesting something else then please provide link for the same @KevinKokomani